# Handling Debug error for "No" and "Cancel" for Application.GetSaveAsFilename

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting debug error when I click "No" or "Cancel" for [replacing the file an existing in the location I am trying to save the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QbsY.jpg) What am I missing here?

```
Sub ExportS()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NewName As Variant
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant

    Set ws = Workbooks("PAP_Macro_v1.xlsm").Worksheets("Export by country")     
    NewName = ws.[H4]        

sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=NewName, _
fileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If sFileSaveName <> False Then
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
Else
MsgBox "File is not being saved, export failed!"
.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you get, and on which line?

Comment: `.Close SaveChanges:=False` this line looks wrong

Comment: I would like to know how many open workbooks (related to the code) there are. Obviously there is `Pap_Macro_v1.xlsm`. Then there is a 'misterious' `ActiveWorkbook` and finally there is `ThisWorkbook` i.e. the workbook containing this code. Can you tell me if two of them are the same?

Comment: hi Tim, there are 3 open workbooks, Pap_Macro_v1.xlsm. ActiveWorkbook is correct in this instance as I have a set of data from a working sheet of mine copied to a new workbook and I am needing to save the active workbook. Managed to solve the overwrite prompt issue now.

Comment: In which workbook is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an error, it's a prompt. Excel is prompting whether to overwrite the existing file. You can disable that by toggling `Application.DisplayAlerts` off (and back on when you're done!) - with `DisplayAlerts` off, an existing file will just silently be overwritten - user won't get the opportunity to cancel the operation.

The prompt is popped during the execution of the `SaveAs` method, and if you cancel that prompt then `Workbook.SaveAs` needs a way to tell the caller "hey wait no, that didn't go as planned" - and it raises an error... that you should be handling regardless of user cancelling a prompt:

```
    If VarType(sFileSaveName) <> vbBoolean Then
        On Error GoTo CleanFail 'handle cancellation / other unexpected issues
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        MsgBox "File is not being saved, export failed!"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "File was not saved."
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Any code that involves accessing the file system should always handle errors.

That said, `Workbook.Close` looks like it's missing a `Workbook` object here:

> ```
> .Close SaveChanges:=False
> ```

Given the other branch is working off `ActiveWorkbook`, presumably this was the intent here as well:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Consider qualifying it with a more specific workbook object for more reliable code.

Comment: The error occurs after the prompt when `No` or `Cancel` are chosen.

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes, and with `Application.DisplayAlerts` off, there's no prompt, the file is just overwritten. I've edited, to clarify.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu! It is working now, so I am missing the handler. Noted on ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False as well. This is so cool, problem solved!! I am learning VBA from scratch, considered this a good learning for me :-) Thanks again for helping me.